# Weird error while trying to attach default sharepoint workflow to Document Library in a console application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I am trying to loop though all the document libraries in a sharepoint site and attach the default sharepoint approval workflow [Approval - Sharepoint 2010] to each of them. This is something quite basic yet I am getting a really weird error.

Here is the code for the console application- [actually you can try this on your machine and see if it gives the same error]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace TestApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        webUrl = args[1];

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //assume that both Tasks and Workflow History lists exist
                SPList taskList = web.Lists["Tasks"];;
                SPList historyList = web.Lists["Workflow History"];

                //loop through the workfows in the web and grab the one you want by name
                SPWorkflowTemplate wfTemp = null;
                foreach (SPWorkflowTemplate wt in web.WorkflowTemplates)
                {
                    if (wt.Name == "Approval - SharePoint 2010")
                    {
                        wfTemp = wt;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                SPWorkflowAssociation workFlow = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(wfTemp, wfTemp.Name, taskList, historyList);
                workFlow.AllowManual = true;
                workFlow.AutoStartChange = false;
                workFlow.AutoStartCreate = true;
                workFlow.AssociationData = null;

                List<SPList> coll = new List<SPList>(web.Lists.Count);
                foreach (SPList l in web.Lists) coll.Add(l);

                foreach (SPList list in coll)
                {
                    if (list is SPDocumentLibrary)
                    {
                        SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
                        try
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);
                            docLib.EnableModeration = true;
                            docLib.Update();
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing list:" + list.Title + " in web " +
                                web.Title + " Got exception: " + ex.Message + "; " +
                            ex.InnerException);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console app will be invoked like this -

TestApp.exe http://www.site.com

If the site has more than more document libraries, there is no error when it loops through the first one. but when it tries to process the second document library it encounters the error

I am getting the error at this line

`docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);`

The details of the error are as follows-

ErrorMessage=""
ErrorCode = -2146232060
Inner Exception = {"0x80131904stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000015A62C) at 0x000007FEEA47A62C\nstswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000015A67B) at 0x000007FEEA47A67B\nstswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000016D696) at 0x000007FEEA48D696\nstswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000016E747) at 0x000007FEEA48E747\nstswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001725C5) at 0x000007FEEA4925C5\nOWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DA8EA) at 0x000007FEE9C3A8EA\nmscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BCD67) at 0x000007FEF933CD67\nMicrosoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000104A86) at 0x000007FEEA2B4A86\nMicrosoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AAC9DA) at 0x000007FEEE3DC9DA\nMicrosoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001B31214) at 0x000007FEEE461214\nMicrosoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001DA6D70) at 0x000007FEEE6D6D70\n"}
NativeErrorMessage= FAILED hr detected (hr = 0x80131904)

NativeStackTrace= stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000015A62C) at 0x000007FEEA47A62C
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000015A67B) at 0x000007FEEA47A67B
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000016D696) at 0x000007FEEA48D696
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=000000000016E747) at 0x000007FEEA48E747
stswel.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000001725C5) at 0x000007FEEA4925C5
OWSSVR.DLL: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000000DA8EA) at 0x000007FEE9C3A8EA
mscorwks.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=00000000002BCD67) at 0x000007FEF933CD67
Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000000104A86) at 0x000007FEEA2B4A86
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001AAC9DA) at 0x000007FEEE3DC9DA
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001B31214) at 0x000007FEEE461214
Microsoft.SharePoint.ni.dll: (unresolved symbol, module offset=0000000001DA6D70) at 0x000007FEEE6D6D70

StackTrace =    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddWorkflowAssociation(String bstrUrl, Guid associationId, Guid baseId, Guid parentId, String pwzName, String pwzDescription, String pwzStatusFieldName, Guid& pListId, Object varContentTypeIdBytes, Guid& pTaskListId, Guid& pHistoryListId, String pwzTaskListTitle, String pwzHistoryListTitle, Int32 userId, Int32 configuration, Int32 autoCleanupDays, UInt64 iPermissionsManual, String pwzInstantiationParams)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAssociationCollection.AddCore(SPWorkflowAssociation wa, Guid id, SPList list, Boolean forceUtilityListCreation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPListWorkflowAssociationCollection.Add(SPWorkflowAssociation workflowAssociation)
   at TestApp.Program.AttachWorkflowToDocumentLibrary(SPWorkflowAssociation workflow, SPDocumentLibrary docLib, SPWeb web) in D:\VSTest\Professional Services\OM\OM\TestApp\Program.cs:line 160

Can somebody throw some light on this ?